# JVM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION after few hours

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss7.x, jvm-crash

Jboss crashes abruptly at regular interval.

Below is the Crash Report generated by Jboss.. Any help to debug the issue would be much appreciated..

hs_err_pid207996.log

#
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006db02f8e, pid=207996, tid=183144
 JRE version: 6.0_39-b04
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 V  [jvm.dll+0x242f8e]

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000012fcd800):  JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.150.42.92" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=183144, stack(0x000000000dbf0000,0x000000000dcf0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000025

Stack: [0x000000000dbf0000,0x000000000dcf0000],  sp=0x000000000dcee050,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x242f8e]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

```
Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000008cf4800 JavaThread "Thread-758 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=109576, stack(0x0000000010c10000,0x0000000010d10000)]
  0x00000000113d9800 JavaThread "Thread-757 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=103040, stack(0x00000000101f0000,0x00000000102f0000)]
  0x0000000008cef800 JavaThread "Thread-681 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=73020, stack(0x000000000eaf0000,0x000000000ebf0000)]
  0x0000000008cee800 JavaThread "Thread-680 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=104632, stack(0x000000000e9f0000,0x000000000eaf0000)]
  0x00000000141a1800 JavaThread "Thread-679 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=104584, stack(0x000000000e5f0000,0x000000000e6f0000)]
  0x000000001474e800 JavaThread "Thread-678 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=101508, stack(0x000000000e4f0000,0x000000000e5f0000)]
  0x0000000009bb2000 JavaThread "Thread-756 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=104620, stack(0x000000000e2f0000,0x000000000e3f0000)]
  0x000000001474e000 JavaThread "Thread-677 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=104608, stack(0x000000000e1f0000,0x000000000e2f0000)]
  0x0000000009bb2800 JavaThread "Thread-755 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=104612, stack(0x000000000e0f0000,0x000000000e1f0000)]
  0x000000001474d000 JavaThread "Thread-676 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=90168, stack(0x000000000def0000,0x000000000dff0000)]
  0x000000001474c800 JavaThread "Thread-754 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=104640, stack(0x000000000ddf0000,0x000000000def0000)]
  0x0000000011e5c000 JavaThread "Thread-753 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=104604, stack(0x000000000daf0000,0x000000000dbf0000)]
  0x0000000011e5d800 JavaThread "Thread-752 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=104580, stack(0x000000000d9f0000,0x000000000daf0000)]
  0x000000001474c000 JavaThread "Thread-675 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=99036, stack(0x000000000d5f0000,0x000000000d6f0000)]
  0x0000000008276800 JavaThread "Thread-674 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=96676, stack(0x000000000d2f0000,0x000000000d3f0000)]
  0x0000000008276000 JavaThread "Thread-673 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=68424, stack(0x000000000cff0000,0x000000000d0f0000)]
  0x0000000008277800 JavaThread "Thread-672 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=92732, stack(0x000000000cbf0000,0x000000000ccf0000)]
  0x000000000851b800 JavaThread "Thread-671 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=95328, stack(0x000000000c7f0000,0x000000000c8f0000)]
  0x0000000011e5d000 JavaThread "Thread-751 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=93728, stack(0x000000000c3f0000,0x000000000c4f0000)]
  0x000000000851c800 JavaThread "Thread-670 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=100488, stack(0x000000000c2f0000,0x000000000c3f0000)]
  0x000000000851a000 JavaThread "Thread-669 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=84460, stack(0x000000000c1f0000,0x000000000c2f0000)]
  0x000000001e578800 JavaThread "Thread-750 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=96840, stack(0x000000000bff0000,0x000000000c0f0000)]
  0x0000000011e5f000 JavaThread "Thread-668 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=99004, stack(0x000000000bdf0000,0x000000000bef0000)]
  0x00000000162bb000 JavaThread "Thread-749 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=100152, stack(0x000000000bbf0000,0x000000000bcf0000)]
  0x000000000fa0e800 JavaThread "Thread-748 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=100460, stack(0x000000000b9f0000,0x000000000baf0000)]
  0x000000000fa0e000 JavaThread "Thread-747 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=100560, stack(0x000000000b8f0000,0x000000000b9f0000)]
  0x000000000851b000 JavaThread "Thread-746 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=94488, stack(0x000000000b6f0000,0x000000000b7f0000)]
  0x000000000fa0a800 JavaThread "Thread-745 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=86064, stack(0x000000000b5f0000,0x000000000b6f0000)]
  0x000000001675a000 JavaThread "Thread-667 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=94536, stack(0x000000000b4f0000,0x000000000b5f0000)]
  0x000000001675c000 JavaThread "Thread-744 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=92004, stack(0x000000000b3f0000,0x000000000b4f0000)]
  0x000000001675d000 JavaThread "Thread-666 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=94484, stack(0x000000000b1f0000,0x000000000b2f0000)]
  0x000000001307c800 JavaThread "Thread-743 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=72592, stack(0x000000000b0f0000,0x000000000b1f0000)]
  0x000000000fa0a000 JavaThread "Thread-742 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=94528, stack(0x000000000aef0000,0x000000000aff0000)]
  0x000000000fa06000 JavaThread "Thread-741 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=76688, stack(0x000000000d1f0000,0x000000000d2f0000)]
  0x0000000012af7800 JavaThread "Thread-740 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=70528, stack(0x000000000d0f0000,0x000000000d1f0000)]
  0x000000001675b800 JavaThread "Thread-663 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=76404, stack(0x000000000caf0000,0x000000000cbf0000)]
  0x00000000141a0800 JavaThread "Thread-662 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14924, stack(0x000000000c9f0000,0x000000000caf0000)]
  0x0000000012eb6800 JavaThread "Thread-661 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=47476, stack(0x000000000c6f0000,0x000000000c7f0000)]
  0x00000000113da000 JavaThread "Thread-735 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=38036, stack(0x000000000bcf0000,0x000000000bdf0000)]
  0x0000000008274800 JavaThread "Thread-733 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=30516, stack(0x000000000b7f0000,0x000000000b8f0000)]
  0x00000000113da800 JavaThread "Thread-658 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7172, stack(0x000000000b2f0000,0x000000000b3f0000)]
  0x00000000162ba800 JavaThread "Thread-729 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=63148, stack(0x000000000aff0000,0x000000000b0f0000)]
  0x0000000011e5e800 JavaThread "Thread-649 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-1265158558)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=185848, stack(0x000000001b200000,0x000000001b300000)]
  0x000000000f7a0800 JavaThread "Thread-718 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=206032, stack(0x000000000c0f0000,0x000000000c1f0000)]
  0x0000000008275000 JavaThread "Thread-710 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=177716, stack(0x0000000017a60000,0x0000000017b60000)]
  0x00000000141a3000 JavaThread "Thread-705 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=230556, stack(0x000000000baf0000,0x000000000bbf0000)]
  0x0000000008519800 JavaThread "Thread-697 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=217932, stack(0x000000000dff0000,0x000000000e0f0000)]
  0x000000001675b000 JavaThread "Thread-680 (HornetQ-remoting-threads-HornetQServerImpl::serverUUID=d29d19e4-f264-11e4)" [_thread_blocked, id=175136, stack(0x000000000c8f0000,0x000000000c9f0000)]
  0x0000000012ca8000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(6)-10.150.42.92" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=173564, stack(0x000000000c4f0000,0x000000000c5f0000)]
  0x0000000012fca000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(5)-10.150.42.92" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=194672, stack(0x000000000dcf0000,0x000000000ddf0000)]
=>0x0000000012fcd800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.150.42.92" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=183144, stack(0x000000000dbf0000,0x000000000dcf0000)]
  0x0000000009ccf800 JavaThread "JMX server connection timeout 216560" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=196736, stack(0x000000000d7f0000,0x000000000d8f0000)]
  0x0000000009cd0000 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=156156, stack(0x000000000d6f0000,0x000000000d7f0000)]
  0x0000000009ccd800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=190580, stack(0x000000000d4f0000,0x000000000d5f0000)]
```

Comment: If the JVM crashes, there is a bug in the JVM itself or in some native code. Have you provided any native code as part of your application? If not, the cause is not a bug in *your* code, and so there is nothing much we can do.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.. 

Then how can i debug what is the root cause for the error. Because I just get only the hs_err_pid<pid>.log file being generated after the Crash. I used the Jconsole to Monitor the threads but cudn't get any valid info.